# Safety of SMB versus SFTP

Tags: ssh, security, samba, remote, sftp

I have a server with OpenSSH enabled. I use it to make distant backups. I mainly use rsync over SSH and SFTP. I understood that these protocols are quite safe.

I am interested in enabling Samba share on the server so that I can access content easily with some IOS apps that I have.

My question is as follows:
- Is Samba a secure protocol?
- Is the security level similar to SSH?
- Would you guys rather stick with SSH/SFTP instead of opening up SMB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Samba is not a secure protocol. The data isn't encrypted during transport.

Which protocol I would choose would depend on the environment. If I'm on an internal network, Samba is fine. If I'm accessing the data remotely, either SSH/SCP or some VPN solution would be preferable from a security standpoint.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the information I was looking for.

Indeed, I want to access my data outside my home network. I think I'll stick with SFTP/SSH.

Comment: http://news.samba.org/announcements/3.2_press_release/ ... Now, no idea if your IOS apps support encryption or not.

Comment: Link above is dead. To configure samba with SSL: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configuring_LDAP_over_SSL_(LDAPS)_on_a_Samba_AD_DC

Answer (score 2):

SAMBA is not a protocol rather than implementation to the SMB protocol.

To say that SMB is not secure is not the right sentence to say because SMB protocol has 3 dialects 1, 2 and 3, the SMBv3 version is a more secure SMB transaction and it support encrypted (CCM and GCM algorithm) the user just need to config the Share folder to be an encrypted one.